# Return class element to default

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have 4 arrows that each one moving the piece element 
now i want to create a reset button that will return the piece to the default place

```
//piece object
var piece = {};
piece.el = $('#piece');
piece.moveDelta = function(dx, dy){
    var pos = this.el.position();
    this.el.css('left', pos.left+dx);
    this.el.css('top', pos.top+dy);
};
$(document).ready(function(){
    //init deltas
    $('#btn-up').data('dx', 0).data('dy', -100);
    $('#btn-left').data('dx', -100).data('dy', 0);
    $('#btn-right').data('dx', 100).data('dy', 0);
    $('#btn-down').data('dx', 0).data('dy', 100);
    //assign click event
    $('.btn-arrow').click(function(){
        piece.moveDelta($(this).data('dx'), $(this).data('dy'));
    });
});
```

Comment: usually i'm working on the server side and dont have problems likes this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
   //piece object
var piece = {};

var defaultX = null;
var defaultY = null;

piece.el = $('#piece');
piece.moveDelta = function(dx, dy){
    var pos = this.el.position();
    if(defaultX === null && defaultY === null ){
         defaultX = pos.left;
         defaultY = pos.top;
    }
    this.el.css('left', pos.left+dx);
    this.el.css('top', pos.top+dy);
};
piece.reset = function () {
   this.el.css('left', defaultX);
   this.el.css('top', defaultY);
};
$(document).ready(function(){
    //init deltas
    $('#btn-up').data('dx', 0).data('dy', -100);
    $('#btn-left').data('dx', -100).data('dy', 0);
    $('#btn-right').data('dx', 100).data('dy', 0);
    $('#btn-down').data('dx', 0).data('dy', 100);


    //assign click event
    $('.btn-arrow').click(function(){
        piece.moveDelta($(this).data('dx'), $(this).data('dy'));
    });
    $("#btn-reset").click(function(){
       piece.reset();
    });

});
```

you can use the `reset` method defined above. [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/8gyFE/1/)

Comment: You should call the reset method on clicking reset button. Take a look at http://jsfiddle.net/8gyFE/1/. I have updated the answer as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the CSS properties to an empty string to reset them: http://jsfiddle.net/myJCq/.

```
piece.reset = function() {
    this.el.css({ left: '', top: '' });
};
```

Comment: what if the piece was initially positioned using left and top properties. i.e, <piece style="left:100px;top:200px;"></piece>

Comment: @Selvaraj M A: Well, then your solution will work :) But if it isn't the case, this may be simpler.

Comment: @shaharnakash: You didn't bind any event handler to the reset button, so nothing happens when it's clicked. See my fiddle for a working solution.